# C++ class member function to c function

Tags: c++, c

I have a C function that resive other C function like argument, this function is a part of C library and I need work with this but with a C++ function, member of a class.

The function definition that pass like argument:

```
void __stdcall CallbackFunctionC(unsigned long esrParam);
```

The definition of the function that resive is:

```
int void __stdcall SetESR( void (__stdcall *esr)(unsigned long esrParam) );
```

I want pass a member class function with the same definition but I can´t.

This a example of the success code with a C function:

```
class ClassTest
{
public:
    void Test();
}
void __stdcall CallbackFunctionC(unsigned long esrParam);

void ClassTest::Test()
{
    SetESR(CallbackFunctionC);
}
void __stdcall CallbackFunctionC(unsigned long esrParam)
{
//Do something
}
```

I need pass a function member but this is thrown an error.
Example of the error code:

```
class ClassTest
{
public:
    void __stdcall CallbackFunctionCPP(unsigned long esrParam);
    void Test();
}

void ClassTest::Test()
{
    SetESR(CallbackFunctionCPP);
}

void ClassTest::CallbackFunctionCPP(unsigned long esrParam)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Error:

```
Error   3   error C3867: 'ClassTest::CallbackFunctionCPP': function call missing argument list; use '&ClassTest::CallbackFunctionCPP' to create a pointer to member ...\ClassTest.cpp   XXXX    1   ClassTest
```

Comment: For c callbacks, you need to provide a `static` class member function. Implicit passing of `this` pointer isn't supported from c.

Comment: Have you even read the error message? It tells you at least 1 thing that is wrong and also tells you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a kind of wrapper with a pointer:

```
    class ClassTest
    {
    public:
        ClassTest();
        void CallbackFunctionCPP(unsigned long esrParam);
        void Test();
    }
    void __stdcall CallbackFunctionC(unsigned long esrParam);

    //Pointer to CPP class
    ClassTest* _ClassTest;

    ClassTest::ClassTest()
    {   
        //Initialization of pointer to CPP class under constructor
        _ClassTest = this;
    }

    void ClassTest::CallbackFunctionCPP(unsigned long esrParam)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    void ClassTest::Test()
    {
        SetESR(CallbackFunctionC);
    }

    void __stdcall CallbackFunctionC(unsigned long esrParam);
    {
        //Use CPP member funtion across C function
        _ClassTest->CallbackFunctionCPP(esrParam);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to be sure that your function definition is correct. What I see in your code is that you declared a member function with parameter and you define the same member function whitout parameter. You should define it like you declared it.

```
void ClassTest::CallbackFunction(unsigned long esrParam)
{
    //do somthing
}
```

Other thing is, you cannot create a callback function with a member function. You need to add a static function.

```
class ClassTest
{
public:
    static void CallbackFunction(unsigned long esrParam); // <-- static function
    void Test();
};
```

The second part of your code is realy strange, i don't really understand what are you trying to do. Why are you passing your callback function to himself. That doesn't make sense. Usually a callback function is given to another object that the object himself(so to another class) and the other class keep the pointer of your function to call it later.

And the last thing is, you really dont need the __stdcall. This is Win32 API convention and it has nothing to do specificlly with callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Type this code:

```
class ClassTest
{
public:
    void Test();
void __stdcall CallbackFunction(unsigned long esrParam);
};
```

Instead of:

```
class ClassTest
{
public:
    void Test();
}
void __stdcall CallbackFunction(unsigned long esrParam);
```

Since the class must terminate with a semicolon (`;`)
and  `void __stdcall CallbackFunction(unsigned long esrParam);` isn't declared as a member of class i.e: inside a class.